# How to create a sequency by group from a specific string in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, sequence

I would like to create a sequence of numbers within a group but starting from a specific string.

In this example, If the string matches UNP then sequence (`seq` column) should start from the next row.

| ColA | Colb | Seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | HM | 0 |
| A | RES | 0 |
| A | UNP | 0 |
| A | RES | 1 |
| A | RES | 2 |
| A | HM | 3 |
| B | HM | 0 |
| B | RES | 0 |
| B | UNP | 0 |
| B | RES | 1 |
| B | UNP | 2 |
| C | UNP | 0 |

Only 1st instance of UNP should be considered not every instance on UNP for each group

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need seq coloumn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a column specifying the first occurrence of "UNP", then use `cumsum()` and `lag()` to calculate the `Seq` column.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
ColA    Colb    Seq
A   HM  0
A   RES 0
A   UNP 0
A   RES 1
A   RES 2
A   HM  3
B   HM  0
B   RES 0
B   UNP 0
B   RES 1
B   UNP 2
C   UNP 0") %>% 
  select(-Seq)

df %>% 
  group_by(ColA, Colb) %>% 
  mutate(seq_count = ifelse(first(Colb) == "UNP" & !duplicated(Colb), 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(ColA) %>% 
  mutate(Seq = lag(cumsum(cumsum(seq_count)), default = 0), .keep = "unused")
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#> # Groups:   ColA [3]
#>    ColA  Colb    Seq
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 A     HM        0
#>  2 A     RES       0
#>  3 A     UNP       0
#>  4 A     RES       1
#>  5 A     RES       2
#>  6 A     HM        3
#>  7 B     HM        0
#>  8 B     RES       0
#>  9 B     UNP       0
#> 10 B     RES       1
#> 11 B     UNP       2
#> 12 C     UNP       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Benson, But its not working when there is UNP followed by UNP it should count from the first instance of UNP. I have edited my question ( look for row 11)

Comment: @asaha See my updated answer :)